# How can I access the first property of a nested property?

Tags: javascript, api

[image]

Every pages property has a first property with a random name. How can I access this property?

I thought about pages[0] but it's not an array.

I'm dealing with an API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Object.values()` to convert the object to an array, then get the first value.

```
Object.values(pages)[0]
```

Comment: How can I use this when accessing properties? Like this, for example:
`response.data.query.pages[0].thumbnail.source`

Comment: Replace `pages` with `response.data.query.pages`: `Object.values(response.data.query.pages)[0].thumbnail.source`

Comment: It worked! Thank you.

`const firstValue = Object.values(response.data.query.pages)[0];
console.log(firstValue.thumbnail.source);`

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is only one nested object, you can use this to get the driver object.

```js
pages[Object.keys(pages)[0]]
```